# SP 2010- Get all items id in the ListView Webpart/ Caml query applied to ListView Webpart

Tags: 2010, list, list-view, list-view-web-part

I am trying to print all the items displayed in a listview webpart (with paging).

So i want to get the current caml query applied to a listview webpart, so that i can use that caml query to get the item collection and create html to be printed.

Now ListView webpart will be displaying a predefined view and i cannot just consider that View's caml query, since the user might do some extra column filtering . Also i have another connected filter webpart in that page , through which the users can further filter the content. So is there any methiod using which i can get the caml query currently applied to Listview webpart with all these filters.